# Git + Bitbucket - Include code from a subproject within the main project

Tags: git, bitbucket, gitignore, atlassian-sourcetree, subproject

I'm using Bitbucket and SourceTree for version control and I have created a subproject within my main project. The subproject is useful because I can have teams work on just the subproject (in this case client-side code) while hosting everything together on one server. Other teams can work on the entire codebase.

HOWEVER, I cannot check the code from the subproject in as part of the main project. In fact, it always uploads an empty folder, rather than the content of the subfolder (subproject folder).

Here are the steps I went through to try and include the files in my subproject as part of my main repo:

1) remove subproject (folder called "web-app") from .gitignore : 
[image: gitignore]
(web-app folder is no longer greyed out - it is part of the repo)
[image: subproject folder is included]

2) Commit the web-app folder to repo: 
[image]

> ... but all I get included is a commit message. I would expect the
>   hundreds of files in the web-app folder to commit to the project at
>   this point. How can I achieve that?

NB - I don't want to lose the subproject or its version control, I just want it to be part of the main repo

Comment: The main purpose of submodules is to have an independent history. Either you include all of your sources in the "main project" or you have to track them separately.

Comment: Can’t I do both? I want to include the files within that subproject in the bitbucket repo. The changes to that subproject can be tracked as a subproject, that’s fine, but the files need to committed to the main repo

Comment: You can. Sure. But please take a minute and think about that idea. This would mean that you have to commit to two repos every time something changes, or to maually copy changes. It is the opposite of everything git stands for. It is guaranteed, that it will fail. You or any other participant will either forgot to track or make any other fault.

Comment: Committing 2 repos to implement changes is exactly how I need it to work. That way, the team in charge of the subproject can work independently, but I control the master project and therefore nothing gets committed without me committing it. But how do I do it!

Comment: Then just create symlinks or add the folder hierarchy of the submodule to the parent module.

Comment: Sounds good! Not sure I follow you though.. could you put that in an answer with a little explanation and I'll award :)